# Why is point_cloud2.py missing from sensor_msgs in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After subscribing to a PointCloud2 message in ROS2, I want to extract the PointCloud2 points from the message.  In ROS1 I could do that with: sensor_msgs.point_cloud2.read_points().  However, point_cloud2 seems to be missing from sensor_msgs in ROS2.  Here is the basic code I am trying to write:

```
import rclpy 
from rclpy.node import Node 
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2 
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2

class my_node(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('my_node')    
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(PointCloud2,'/points',self.lidar_callback,1)

    def lidar_callback(self, msg):
        pts = point_cloud2.read_points(msg, field_names=['x','y','z','intensity'])
        #Now process pts...
```

The 4th line fails, namely:

```
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2
```

Any insights on how to do this in ROS2 Foxy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357944/why-is-point_cloud2.py-missing-from-sensor_msgs-in-ros2?/) by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/tree/master/sensor_msgs

Not ported yet. https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/tree/noetic-devel/sensor_msgs/src/sensor_msgs looks pretty trivial to port though if you need it. Submit a PR!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-07-24**:
Ah yes, I will do that, but I'm new to this.  How to submit a PR?

Thanks!

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-07-24**:
Through GitHub, you have to understand Git to do so (if you don't know Git, you should really learn, its the basis for modern software development).

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-07-24**:
Okay, I submitted this as a feature request.  Hopefully that is the right thing to do.
Thanks.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-07-24**:
Sure thing, can you mark this answer as correct then?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this has been ported now https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/pull/128.

just waiting on the release to update

---

Originally posted by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) with karma: 191 on 2020-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hazel-rah](https://answers.ros.org/users/144712/hazel-rah/) on 2023-05-03**:
also see the answer from April 6, 2023
https://answers.ros.org/question/411414/i-cant-import-sensor_msgspoint_cloud2/